# If a murder was committed in Antarctica and it was unclear who did it, who would investigate?

Tags: criminal-law, international, jurisdiction, murder

If a murder were committed in Antarctica and it was unclear who did it, what country/agency would investigate? And, if the guilty party were identified, who (if anyone) would have the authority to arrest them?

Comment: Related:  [Which agency or government body should a tourist to Antarctica report to?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/13996/which-agency-or-government-body-should-a-tourist-to-antarctica-report-to)

Answer (score 1):

Various countries have jurisdiction in Antarctica, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctic_Treaty_System#Legal_system.

The geographic limits of each country's jurisdiction are well defined. The USA has jurisdiction if no one else does.

Comment: Question - does your answer change if the murder weapon was an icicle?

Comment: @jqning no, but if wielded by a penguin ...

Comment: `The USA has jurisdiction if no one else does.` WOO! USA! USA! USA! ...Sorry. Instinct.

Comment: "The geographic limits of each country's jurisdiction are well defined" - but in many cases, overlap.  In practise, the murder would probably be investigated by the country running the relevant base.  (Which could be tricky if the murder happened half-way between Rothera [UK] and San Martin [Argentina])

Comment: All of which begs the question of whether Antarctica - and specifically the area where the crime was committed - have any law enforcement officers. GIven that almost everyone there seems to be a scientist, I'm guessing police are few and far between or absent entirely. I suppose people that aren't police officers would be motivated to solve the crime and detain the miscreant if he/she is found, pending evacuation to the relevant country's judicial system.

Comment: @jgning what's the joke here? I am missing it

Answer (score 1):

In the most cases, the country of the citizenship of the victim would do the investigation. If the crime was committed on an Antarctic base running within a specific jurisdiction, such jurisdiction would be also given and investigation would be probably done by that country as well.